# Why does Ray sensor in Blender Game Engine cause actuator to activate superfluously?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In Blender Game Engine, version 2.79, an object has a test Keyboard sensor, with an And controller, that activates an Edit Object actuator to add an object. This works fine. However, when I added a Ray sensor, the same actuator now adds three copies of the new object instead of one. This should *a forteriori* add one or zero objects, because it is the same logic *plus* requiring the Ray sensor. So why is it adding three objects at a time?

Ray sensor deactivated, one blue object added:
[image: Ray sensor deactivated, one blue object added.]

Ray sensor activated, three blue objects added:
[image: Ray sensor activated, three blue objects added.]

Comment: what is it ?? forteriori, i can't understand !

Comment: can you upload your blend to review ? [Upload Blender Stack Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
Your Ray sensor should be set to `Tap` to prevent any extra pulses.

**2.**
Your Ray sensor's option `Invert` is turned on, I don't think this option needs to be on, unless there's some other logic that I'm not getting and the option is internationally turned on.